# Performance after Period of inactivity

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

We have a Google App Engine Service developed. There are two controllers which pull from google datastore however after a lull generally 6:30 AM local Eastern time (services are in us-central) the first pull on these controllers generally results in 30 second latency. Our current thought is to create a scheduled task to keep these services "hot" Is this an appropriate way of thinking or is better to look elsewhere?

Comment: You could have a CRON job run every 10 minutes or so.  I think instances are shut down after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts if just using CPU cycles is sufficient like a sleep() or if IO and/or network traffic would need to have activity too?

Comment: Any activity should be fine, but Ying Li's answer seems to be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using App Engine Standard, then you can use [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuring-warmup-requests), which can help lower you spike latency. If you volume is very flat then you can even just use a [manually scaled](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) instance which is always up.